# create entity with reference to another existing object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Link
{
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public Category(){Links = new List<Link>}
    public virtual IList<Link> Links {get; set;}
}
```

My problem is when I wanna create Link with reference to Category I got a error with foreign key.
I try to use fluent api, get threw repo category but still the same problem.
EF want to create new object of Category.

To pass data I get to controller second repo(category) and pass to viewbag data.
4 hours spent to find solution but still I've got nothing, could someone explain it to me how it work that I cant pass that :/

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your classes need properties that can be mapped to primary keys. This is most commonly done with an `int` called `ID`...

```
public class Link
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Category(){Links = new List<Link>}
    public virtual IList<Link> Links {get; set;}
}
```